# ASP .NET MVC application user in database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want create database using entity framework (code first). And I want change Application User ID type (string->int). How I can do it?

Second question: How I can delete some default columns in table User (example Phone number).

Comment: What did you try so far, and what result did you get?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

To change the primary key of the user entity, you should follow this turorial: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

To remove unecesarry data from user class, you can create your own IdentityUser implementation. Basically you shoud imlement Interface IUser with your own class.
See the hierarhy here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613256(v=vs.108).aspx, and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613291(v=vs.108).aspx